# Integrated File Browser in .NET Winforms?

Tags: winforms, browser, file

I'm looking to integrate a file browser that given a directory uses this as a root (can't go any deeper).

I've used the System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control with some Button controls to support directory navigation (which disables when you hit the root).

It works great except when the window is large it provides a properties bar on the left side that I don't want shown. I don't see any properties of the Browser object that does this.

[link text](http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3542/3675636968_642a678365.jpg)

Does anyone know how to remove this or know of another easy way to pull this off?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [FileBrowser](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/FileBrowser.aspx), there are many configuration options
Hide the left pane and the back button ;-)